# No such table found error in SQLite for multiple tables while writing

Tags: android

I have changed the version from 1 to 2 also. but still its not getting resolved.
My DBAdapter is where I create all the tables

```
package com.example.mydhara;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;



public class DBAdapter {

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDhara.db"; 

public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

//SQL stm to create a Login DB
static String CREATE_TABLE_LOGIN="create table "+"LOGIN"+
                    "( "+"ID"+" integer primary key autoincrement,"+
                    "Name text, RegNo text, USERNAME text, PASSWORD text);";




    //SQL stm to create a Register DB
 static String CREATE_TABLE_REGISTER="create table "+"REGISTER"+
                    "( "+"ID"+" integer primary key autoincrement,"+
                    "Name text, RegNo text, EventName text,Branch text, Year integer);";

   private final Context context; 
private DataBaseHelper dbHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;

    /**
    * Constructor
    * @param ctx
     */
public DBAdapter(Context ctx)
{
    this.context = ctx;
    this.dbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this.context);
}

private static class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
{
    DataBaseHelper(Context context) 
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
    {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_LOGIN);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_REGISTER);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
    {               
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS CREATE_TABLE_LOGIN");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS CREATE_TABLE_REGISTER");
            onCreate(db);
    }
} 

     /**
    * open the db
    * @return this
   * @throws SQLException
    * return type: DBAdapter
    */
public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException 
{
    this.db = this.dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

/**
 * close the db 
 * return type: void
 */
public void close() 
{
    this.dbHelper.close();
}
}
```

I have 2 tables, this is one of the adapters
package com.example.mydhara;

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.widget.Toast;

 public class LoginDataBaseAdapter {


 private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "LOGIN";  
/*//Column no for each record
public static final int NAME_COLUMN=1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Mydhara";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;*/




//Variable to hold db instance
public SQLiteDatabase db;

//Context of the app using the database
private final Context context;

//DataBase open/upgrade
private DataBaseHelper dbHelper;



 private static class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DBAdapter.CREATE_TABLE_LOGIN, null, DBAdapter.DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            //db.execSQL(DATABASE_TABLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        //  db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS CREATE_TABLE_LOGIN");
        }
    }

public LoginDataBaseAdapter(Context _context)
{
    this.context=_context;

    //dbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}


//Opening database
public LoginDataBaseAdapter open() throws SQLException
{
    this.dbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this.context);
    this.db=this.dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}


//closing the database
public void close()
{
    db.close();
}

//getting an instance of db
public SQLiteDatabase getDatabaseInstance()
{
    return db;
}


//Inserting a value
public void insertEntry(String name,String regno, String userName,String password)
{
    ContentValues newvalues=new ContentValues();
    //Assign values for each row
    newvalues.put("Name", name);
    newvalues.put("RegNo", regno);
    newvalues.put("USERNAME", userName);
    newvalues.put("PASSWORD", password);
    //inserting
    db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, newvalues);
    Toast.makeText(context, "Successfully Inserted", 7000).show();
}

//Deleting a value
public int deleteEntry(String UserName)
{
    int no_of_records=db.delete("LOGIN", "USERNAME=?", new String[]{UserName});
    Toast.makeText(context, "No of Enteries Deleted are "+no_of_records, 7000).show();
    return no_of_records;
}

//Getting single entry for a query
public  String getSingleEntry(String UserName)
{

    Cursor cursor=db.query(DATABASE_TABLE,null," USERNAME=?",new String[]{UserName},null,null,null);
    if(cursor.getCount()<1)
    {
        cursor.close();
        return "Not EXIST";
    }
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String password=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("PASSWORD"));
    cursor.close();
    return password;
}
//getting single username

public String getSingleUs(String UserName)
{
    Cursor cursor =db.query(DATABASE_TABLE,null,"USERNAME=?",new String[]{UserName},null,null,null);
    if(cursor.getCount()<1)
    {
        cursor.close();
        return "Not EXIST";
    }
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String userName=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("USERNAME"));
    cursor.close();
    return UserName;    
}

//Update a value
public void updateEntry(String userName,String password)
{
    ContentValues updateValues=new ContentValues();

    updateValues.put("PASSWORD", password);

    db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, updateValues, "USERNAME=?", new String[]{userName});

}
}
```

Login(Main.java)

```
 package com.example.mydhara;


 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener  {

Button blogin,bsignup;
TextView tvUser,tvPass;
EditText etUser,etPass;

LoginDataBaseAdapter loginDataBaseAdapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //get instance of db adapter
    loginDataBaseAdapter = new LoginDataBaseAdapter(this);
    loginDataBaseAdapter = loginDataBaseAdapter.open();


    //initialising all the buttons,textview and EditText

    blogin= (Button) findViewById(R.id.blogin); 
    bsignup= (Button) findViewById(R.id.bsignup);

    etUser= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUser);
    etPass= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPass);

    blogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String us=etUser.getText().toString();
        String ps=etPass.getText().toString();

        if(us.equals("")||ps.equals(""))
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The field are empty", 7000).show();
            etUser.setText("");
            etPass.setText("");


            return ;
        }
        String storedUs = loginDataBaseAdapter.getSingleUs(us);
        if(us.equals(storedUs))
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "the username already exists", 7000).show();
            etUser.setText("");
            etPass.setText("");
        }
        String storedpassword = loginDataBaseAdapter.getSingleEntry(us);

        if(ps.equals(storedpassword))
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successfully Logged In", 7000).show();
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SelectForum.class);
            startActivity(i);

            return ;
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The username or password entered is invalid", 7000).show();
            etUser.setText("");
            etPass.setText("");
            return ;
        }


    }
    });


    bsignup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Signup", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Signup.class);
            startActivity(i);
    }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {    
    super.onDestroy();
    loginDataBaseAdapter.close();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}}
```

LogCat.

```
04-13 09:54:42.560: I/SqliteDatabaseCpp(2075): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table: LOGIN, db=/data/data/com.example.mydhara/databases/create table LOGIN( ID integer primary key autoincrement,Name text, RegNo text, USERNAME text, PASSWORD text);
04-13 09:54:42.630: E/SQLiteDatabase(2075): Error inserting Name=Admin USERNAME=admin PASSWORD=admin RegNo=cse11007
04-13 09:54:42.630: E/SQLiteDatabase(2075): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: LOGIN: , while compiling: INSERT INTO LOGIN(Name,USERNAME,PASSWORD,RegNo) VALUES (?,?,?,?)
04-13 09:54:42.630: E/SQLiteDatabase(2075):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
04-13 09:54:42.630: E/SQLiteDatabase(2075):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:68)
04-13 09:54:42.630: E/SQLiteDatabase(2075):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileSql(SQLiteProgram.java:143)
04-13 09:54:42.630: E/SQLiteDatabase(2075):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileAndbindAllArgs(SQLiteProgram.java:361)
04-13 09:54:42.630: E/SQLiteDatabase(2075):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.acquireAndLock(SQLiteStatement.java:260)
04-13 09:54:42.630: E/SQLiteDatabase(2075):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:112)
04-13 09:54:42.630: E/SQLiteDatabase(2075):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1718)
04-13 09:54:42.630: E/SQLiteDatabase(2075):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1591)
04-13 09:54:42.630: E/SQLiteDatabase(2075):     at com.example.mydhara.LoginDataBaseAdapter.insertEntry(LoginDataBaseAdapter.java:92)
04-13 09:54:42.630: E/SQLiteDatabase(2075):     at com.example.mydhara.Signup$1.onClick(Signup.java:75)
04-13 09:54:42.630: E/SQLiteDatabase(2075):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
04-13 09:54:42.630: E/SQLiteDatabase(2075):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
04-13 09:54:42.630: E/SQLiteDatabase(2075):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
04-13 09:54:42.630: E/SQLiteDatabase(2075):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-13 09:54:42.630: E/SQLiteDatabase(2075):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-13 09:54:42.630: E/SQLiteDatabase(2075):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
04-13 09:54:42.630: E/SQLiteDatabase(2075):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-13 09:54:42.630: E/SQLiteDatabase(2075):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-13 09:54:42.630: E/SQLiteDatabase(2075):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
04-13 09:54:42.630: E/SQLiteDatabase(2075):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:592)
04-13 09:54:42.630: E/SQLiteDatabase(2075):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-13 09:54:50.920: I/SqliteDatabaseCpp(2075): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table: LOGIN, db=/data/data/com.example.mydhara/databases/create table LOGIN( ID integer primary key autoincrement,Name text, RegNo text, USERNAME text, PASSWORD text);
04-13 09:54:50.930: D/AndroidRuntime(2075): Shutting down VM
04-13 09:54:50.930: W/dalvikvm(2075): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2ce6180)
04-13 09:54:50.930: D/AndroidRuntime(2075): procName from cmdline: com.example.mydhara
04-13 09:54:50.930: E/AndroidRuntime(2075): in writeCrashedAppName, pkgName :com.example.mydhara
04-13 09:54:50.930: D/AndroidRuntime(2075): file written successfully with content: com.example.mydhara StringBuffer : ;com.example.mydhara
04-13 09:54:50.940: I/Process(2075): Sending signal. PID: 2075 SIG: 9
04-13 09:54:50.940: E/AndroidRuntime(2075): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-13 09:54:50.940: E/AndroidRuntime(2075): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: LOGIN: , while compiling: SELECT * FROM LOGIN WHERE USERNAME=?
04-13 09:54:50.940: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
04-13 09:54:50.940: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:68)
04-13 09:54:50.940: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileSql(SQLiteProgram.java:143)
04-13 09:54:50.940: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileAndbindAllArgs(SQLiteProgram.java:361)
04-13 09:54:50.940: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:127)
04-13 09:54:50.940: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:94)
04-13 09:54:50.940: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:53)
04-13 09:54:50.940: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:47)
04-13 09:54:50.940: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1564)
04-13 09:54:50.940: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1449)
04-13 09:54:50.940: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1405)
04-13 09:54:50.940: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1485)
04-13 09:54:50.940: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):     at com.example.mydhara.LoginDataBaseAdapter.getSingleUs(LoginDataBaseAdapter.java:123)
04-13 09:54:50.940: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):     at com.example.mydhara.Main$1.onClick(Main.java:57)
04-13 09:54:50.940: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
04-13 09:54:50.940: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
04-13 09:54:50.940: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
04-13 09:54:50.940: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-13 09:54:50.940: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-13 09:54:50.940: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
04-13 09:54:50.940: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-13 09:54:50.940: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-13 09:54:50.940: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
04-13 09:54:50.940: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:592)
04-13 09:54:50.940: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS CREATE_TABLE_LOGIN` should be `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS LOGIN`, ditto for the next line. As is, `onUpgrade` would fail.

Comment: I tried it but its still giving me the same error.

Comment: @SimplePlan, you simply plagiarized a comment, and the feedback was already given.

Comment: @323go tell me why down voted?BC

Comment: Could you please answer my doubt only.